# [Django]Import data into mysql from file

Tags: mysql, django

I'm trying to import data from a file (3 columns) into my local mysql database. It contains 27442 rows.

```
def import(file):
    base_dir= '/home/xxxxx/Desktop/'
    with open(os.path.join(base_dir, file), 'r') as f:
      for line in f.readlines(): 
         line=line.split() #remove all useless space
         if len(line) >= 3:
             host.objects.create(
                hostaddress=line[0],
                hostname= line[1],
                comment=line[2] #' ' by default
             )
          else:
              raise('Invalid format')
```

Everything seem work properly but when i check the table after importation
I get less than the half of total rows (about 11000).

Django model:

```
class host(models.Model):
   hostname= models.SlugField(max_length=50)
   hostaddress= models.GenericIPAddressField(primary_key=True)
   comment= models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: What is the context you're running this from? Can you show some sample lines from your data file? By the way, it's usually preferable to do `for line in f` rather than `for line in f.readlines()`.

Comment: hi ! i want store in database because i'll use them after to perform an inventory of each device.
in the file i've lines likes this:


    X.X.X.X       Some-things           #Comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is:

```
hostaddress= models.GenericIPAddressField(primary_key=True)
```

primary_key=True automatically sets unique=True. If you have duplicate hostaddress fields in the raw data then only the unique values will be imported.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. 
I  checked the file if there is any duplicates entries. i didn't found